# Duplicate IDs in VCD files

Tags: verilog, waveform, cadence

I peered into one of the VCD files that was generated when I ran a Verilog testbench using Cadence's ncverilog suite. I noticed many wires (belonging to different module scopes though) that had been given the exact same IDs. For example, multiple wires (one being `out[23]`, another being `o_prod[30]`, both belonging to different scopes) had the ID `'`.

How does any waveform viewer know which of those is being referred to when it is reading the value change information?

Comment: Hopefully you know that cadence has its own proprietary format (.trn) that gives you much smaller faster files than vcd. I'm saying this because none of my coworkers knew this until I showed them a few months ago. It's similar to synopsys's fsdb.

Answer (score 1):

Since the VCD file is plain text, it can consume a huge amount of memory, especially for large designs.  Therefore, it is of utmost importance to keep the file size as small as possible.  That is why multiple hierarchical path names which represent the same logical node share the same ID code in the VCD file.  A signal can have many different names through the hierarchy, but they all share the same logic value data and change times.

Every waveform viewer software probably implements it differently, but each unique hierarchical path name is in some sort of hash table which points to a single ID.  The viewer makes all the signal names available to the user to ease debug.  When the user selects `out[23]` and `o_prod[30]` for viewing, the tool simply retrieves the same data for both signals and displays them.